# I don't know how long I'm flag banned for, and that would be useful to know

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-ban

It would be nice if I knew the time I'm banned for - a range of tomorrow - 7 days isn't a very narrow time frame.

Could we be able to see the same "time remaining" that mods can on our flagged page (i.e. can this be made public or user viewable)?

Comment: This number could change in either direction. You could get an extra flag handled from before you were banned. It isn't a common case, though.

Comment: Also http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11028/i-am-getting-a-you-are-currently-banned-from-flagging-message-but-no-clear-en which makes the point rather in more detail.  This should be [tag:bug] not [tag:feature-request] IMHO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After the next build, the ban message on your flag summary page will indicate how long you must wait before flagging again:

> [image: You may raise flags again in 7 days]

Fair warning: flag ban durations are calculated on demand. If more flags are declined after you view this message, the duration may be extended; if more flags are marked helpful, the ban may be lifted entirely. You should treat this as informational, but not conclusive.